# Cannot connect from Spark Streaming to Kafka: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to read from a Kafka topic with Spark Streaming direct stream but I receive the following error:

```
INFO consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:422)
```

I have Kafka 0.7.1 and Spark 1.5.2.

I'm using the following code:

```
  val ssc : StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(60))   
  val topicsSet = Set("myTopic")
  val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]
          ("metadata.broker.list" -> "mybrokerhostname1:9092,mybrokerhostname2:9092")

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], DefaultDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

I am sure that the topic already exists because other applications are correctly reading from it.

Comment: Are you sure network communication from the place you're trying to access Kafka from is correctly configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use older version of kafka, in your case it is ([0.7.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-403?jql=fixVersion%20%3D%200.7.1%20AND%20project%20%3D%20KAFKA)).
If you have a strong reason to use 0.7.1, do let me know.
Looking at your exception, it looks like the application is not able to connect to kafka brokers.

I have used this direct stream api to read from kafka 0.8.2.
https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/TransactionalPerBatch.scala

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Vikas Gite

Comment: You are right. I have tried with Kafka 0.8.2 and it works smoothly. Unfortunately currently our applications are running on Kafka 0.7.1 so we will have to migrate it to 0.8.2, unless anybody knows about a workaround. Thanks for your help!